# Error launching remote program: No such file or directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Anyone have an idea about this

`Error launching remote program: No such file or directory (/Users/muself/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-hlelojuljidnnagbdqzliazpdgmn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myproject.app/myproject).`

The project was working fine with the previous Xcode versions. I have just updated the Xcode to Version 4.3.2 (4E2002), & the error start coming.

I have search on the web, and tried a lot of the options like

Quit Xcode, clear the Derived Data folder, restart the Xcode.
Rename the project,
Reset the device,etc
I also tried this on another machine but did not work, the same problem occurs.

But one thing i have some other projects as well and they are working fine.

Thanks for at least reading this.

Comment: have you tried to "validate settings" (button on the bottom of project settings)? Do you use some static libs in your app?

Comment: Thanks Vov4yk, I have just checked this & know the error has removed, But now the application starts crashing on startup.

Comment: Sorry the crash was not due to this, it is the internal communication error, Thanks Man

Comment: @Vov4yk You should write this as an answer

Answer (score 22):

First try restarting Xcode. If it doesn't work, then try hard reset of your device. This happens to me when I change the bundle identifier of my app. 
**This solution,I found of the above problem its working fine for me.:)**

Comment: +1 because quitting xcode alone did the job for me.  a definitive answer.  thank you!

Comment: @vinnybad your welcome brother,i am very happy to listen that my answer is working for your problem.its my pleasure :):)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to "validate settings" (button on the bottom of project settings)? Do you use some static libs in your app? – ***Vov4yk***

Answer (score 1):

Check your deployment target. I am running Xcode 4.5, and it gave me that cryptic message, while the reason was that my iPad is running version 5.1.1, and my app was set with deployment target of 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I also get same problem. This below solution works for me.
Thats really annoying. This error happens in a number of different situations. Sometime restarting the Xcode, fixes the problem. If not, follow these steps:

1. Disconnect your device.
2. Delete the app from your device.
3. Quit xcode (Don't just simply close the window, quit it)
4. Delete derived data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME -gbrvhlvwmpiobxdujegtghggrffp - or something like that)
5. Now start Xcode, connect device and run the project. It should work fine.

Source: http://dhilipsiva.com/2012/07/24/xcode-could-not-launch-app-no-such-file-or-directory-error.html

Answer (score 0):

Hard reset of the device fixed it for me. i.e. power off and back on.
Quitting Xcode, disconnecting, reconnecting the device etc didn't.

The error occurred just after I had created a new project with the a duplicate Bundle Identifier to another. Both apps coexist OK on the device/ in Xcode, but this does seem to cause the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when I let the build configuration set up as ad-hoc. After I put it back to Debug it worked fine.